# Replace NuGet package with a local dll file

Tags: c#

A project I am working on depends on a NuGet package. The dll file inside package is compiled in Release mode, therefore using debugger to inspect code (which is my goal) is impossible.

I'd like to replace the .dll file with the one I compiled in Debug mode. If I remove the package via NuGet and then add it via `Add Reference`, I get error:

```
Assembly 'AssemblyName' with identity 'AssemblyName, Version=4.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cf7b13ffcb2dde54' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Memory' with identity 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cf7b13ffcb2dde54'
```

What is the correct way to replace a NuGet package .dll with another .dll file? Where can the version number be changed I am using Rider, but learning how to do it in other IDEs is also useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the nuget is using a `specific version of "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1",` and you have `System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0 referenced in your project`. You should update that reference and it should be good. So the problem is with your DLL not the NuGet. Probably when you removed the nuget you **downgraded System.Memory, you should update that explicitly** to the version that the error says it requires through NuGet.

Pro Tip if you want to mess around with nugets:

- It is essentially a ZIP file
- Download Nuget
- Change extension to .zip
- Decompress
- Voila, you have some dll-s

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the author of the nuget package to publish source and debug symbols of the package to a public symbolsource server and reference it. After that you would keep using the release version of the dll but be able to debug into it.