# Replace asp.net core NuGet packages with local dll files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am trying to get rid of nuget packages and have only local dll files in the project.

These packages I have excluded

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
```

So, I've built my solution and imported all the dlls in the project. I can compile it, but the server says:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: ...

But having the same with nuget makes the work fine. What is an alternative to add dlls to the project?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587420/replace-nuget-package-with-a-local-dll-file), but in my case I have too many files with the same name when I put all the dlls in one folder (conflicts)

Comment: From the error specified it sounds like you are missing a `cshtml` file? In your project have you got a `Views` folder?

Comment: It is there, it works. Until I remove these package references and put the dlls from the build folder.

Comment: Copy and pasting from the build folder is probably not the best way to achieve what you are trying to achieve, downloading the package from the nuget site is probably a little better: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/ for example, look for the "download package link" and unzip the package (it's a zip file with dlls inside) and reference that

Comment: Some NuGet packages add important elements into your project file with special build instructions for things like MVC Views. I would look carefully through the XML of your project file and see if something there is trying to reference the packages folder still. On another note: this feels like you're working against the flow of technology's progress, which usually ends up being the wrong decision. Have you considered whether this is an "XY Problem," where you're asking about the solution but you've already chosen the wrong solution for the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Regarding your comment below that you're doing this because apparently your build server does not support restoring from NuGet: Get that fixed instead of trying to work around it - you do not want to have to check in all your dependencies in binary form (or have to rely on recreating folder structures on your build server).

Comment: To back-up what @StriplingWarrior and germi said--you are trying to fix the wrong problem. You should get your build server working with NuGet, and not get rid of NuGet instead.

Comment: worst case is you store the packages in source control and then they are local to the solution.  It will blow out the size of your repo, but at least you will have them

Comment: Also, some nuget pakcages has many dependencies which will installed into projects when you installed it and if you just want to use assembly reference to reference the dlls directly, you will miss them. In addition,some nuget pcackages may have some powershells or target files to do some operation to the project. So l am afraid you should check everything package,also add the dependency dlls into project,and do not forget to execute the related operation of the powershell or target files(if they exist in the nuget package)

Answer (score 1):

You can always add NUget source which is local folder from you drive and make it as default or the only source of dependencies.

Here are more details [Local feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds)

Comment: I need to avoid the use of nuget because of our build server

Comment: Local Nuget can point to relative path. Which will work both on build server and local. If you have everything in repo

Comment: @mognurodro A build server not capable of handling nuget is basically broken. You need to get another one or fix it. Having local repos can still be helpful (saved my skin once) but your focus should be on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace asp.net core NuGet packages with local dll files. What is an
>   alternative to add dlls to the project?
>   I am trying to get rid of nuget packages and have only local dll files
>   in the project.

Nuget is a recommended way to manage the assemblies for your project. When you have access to Internet, using nuget is very convenient for your situation.

But according to your [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369847/how-to-include-nuget-packages-in-a-project-to-make-the-project-portable) here, you're trying to develop/build the project in environment with no Internet. If so, we can still use nuget for this situation:

Step1: Clear all Nuget cache in VS=>Tools=>Options=>Nuget Package Manager=>General. (All packages you once used in VS are cached in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`, we can easy to restore the packages using `nuget store`, so feel free to clear the cache)

Step2: Delete the `bin and obj` folders of your current web project, and then restore packages for only your current project.([nuget restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-the-nugetexe-cli), [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-the-dotnet-cli) or simply rebuild the project in VS,VS will restore the packages for you)

Step3: Now let's navigate to the `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` folder, now every packages in `packages` folder is that your current project depends on. Let's rename the folder name from `packages` to `mypackages`. Now all the packages(assemblies) your project need are in `mypackages` folder.

Step4: We can then copy/move this folder into your project folder. We can add this folder into source control or what depending on your actual needs. You can feel free to deploy your project to another server(no-internet) and continue on your work.

As to how to reference them, you can fetch the assemblies you need from `mypackages` folder and manually reference them.(Add=>Reference=>...). Or use this better way with nuget, add the path where your `mypackages` folder exist to [Package Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources), you can restore the packages for your project easily even in no-Internet environment.

Hope it helps and feel free to let me know if you need any further info or support :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`. You can add a dll for this package and then compile the Project or solution.