# How to include nuget packages in a project to make the project portable

Tags: c#, package, nuget

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587420/replace-nuget-package-with-a-local-dll-file), I decided to use nuget in the project. I would like to make it "portable" - add the used packages in the git repository and requiering no internet connection on the server side. What is the way to do it?

Comment: You should create a build script which will download all the packages and build the project and create deployment package. Yes just need to deploy the application on the server after that

Answer (score 0):

You should add path to the local copy of the repository, your NuGet location to the Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources and install the NuGet from this location instead of installing it from the server or anywhere else.

Having the location of your NuGet files inside the NuGet.config file which is used by Visual Studio when building the project, will download the needed packages from the specified location.